# Django query possibly at the views.py

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skill'

Here is my code below:

```
def create_choice(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        skill = request.POST.get('skill')
        print(skill)
        skill_obj = Skill.objects.get(name=skill)
        price = request.POST.get('price')
        print(price)
        price_obj = Price.objects.get(name=price, skill__name=skill_obj.name)
        Choice.objects.create(skill=skill_obj, price=price_obj)
        return JsonResponse({'created':True})
    return JsonResponse({'created':False}, safe=False)
```

Comment: Show us your Choice model

Comment: share your Choice & Skill model

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your `Choice` model doesn't have a `skill` attribute.